# Highcharts Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'day' of undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts chart that I'm trying to manually set the x axis label format on a click event using:

```
stockchart.xAxis[0].dateTimeLabelFormats.day = "%b %e";
```

However, I receive "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'day' of undefined". Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should be using [`xAxis.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this worked for me thanks to Pawel's suggestion:

```
stockchart.xAxis[0].update({
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: "%b %e"
            }
        });
```